# Umbraco 8: Get all content of specific type in WebAPI class

Tags: umbraco, webapi, umbraco8

**Q) How do I access my website content, e.g. books collection in my WebAPI class?**

In an Umbraco 8 website project, I am using the following in my razor view to get content, which works fine, allowing me to then iterate over the collection and build my page, all great.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels;
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


@{
    var books = Model.Root().DescendantsOfType("Book")
                .Cast<Book>().Where(x => x.ShowInWebsite);
}
//...
```

However, this doesn't compile in my **WebAPI** class - I don't know how to fix the references needed.

**Error I'm getting:**

```
The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context
```

**Other things I've tried:**

```
var books = Umbraco.ContentAtRoot().DescendantsOrSelf().OfTypes("Book");
```

// Which gives error:

```
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>' does not contain a definition for 'DescendantsOrSelf' and the best extension method overload 'PublishedContentExtensions.DescendantsOrSelf(IPublishedContent, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IPublishedContent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @Jannik Anker

I managed to get my collection by so:

```
var parent = Umbraco.ContentAtRoot().First().Children().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Booklist");
if (parent != null) 
{
    var books = parent.Children();
    var test = "";
    foreach (var book in books) 
    {
        test += book.Id + ": " + book.Name + "\r\n";
    }
    return test;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You WebApi class doesn't have a model, but as long as it inherits from UmbracoApiController you should be able to do

```
Umbraco.ContentAtRoot()...
```

instead?

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/

According to https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Querying/IPublishedContent/Collections/#oftypes you should then be able to do

```
Umbraco.ContentAtRoot().DescendantsOrSelf().OfTypes("Book")
```

Comment: Might I then suggest taking a look at which methods are available, in the official documentation? :-) Unless you've already tried it, have a look at https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Querying/IPublishedContent/Collections/#oftypes

Comment: Updated my answer as well ;-)

Comment: I tried that too - see my updated question with the output of the line you suggested.  The docs are of no help either - as they have absolutely no detail on webapi implementations, extremely poor in fact.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dave I see no attempt to use the line I suggested. There is no .DescendantsOfType but there IS a .DescendantsOrSelf() which can be combined with .OfTypes("...")?

Comment: that was a typo from another attempt, I tried that too and have updated the question with the relevant code line & error string.

Comment: Fair enough! Of course ContentAtRoot() is an enumerable, so you'll have to either throw a .First() after it, or iterate through it and perhaps add results of each DescendantsOrSelf() etc to a collection of your own?